# Drupal hide form items completely with states

Tags: javascript

I try to hide a whole date/image/taxonomy block on my node form dependent on a checkbox.
If use the following for my title field it works perfectly. The title field is hidden/visible dependant on the test_box checked value.

```
function interceptor_box_listener(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['test_box'] = array(
    '#title' => t('You want to choose a title?'),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
  );
  $states_array = array(
    'visible' => array(
      'input[name="test_box"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  );
  $form['title']['#states'] = $states_array;
  return $form;
}
```

The point is that I have more complex fields I need to toggle and I'm not able to address them correctly. If I try to adress the following fielditem, nothing happens at all.

```
<div id="edit-field-plakat" class="field-type-image field-name-field-plakat field-widget-image-image form-wrapper">
<div id="edit-field-plakat-und-0-ajax-wrapper">
<div class="form-item form-type-managed-file form-item-field-plakat-und-0">
<label for="edit-field-plakat-und-0">Plakat</label>
<div class="image-widget form-managed-file clearfix"><input type="hidden" value="109" name="field_plakat[und][0][fid]">
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

It tried the following:

```
$form['field_plakat[und][0][fid]']['#states'] = $states_array;
```

Is there any possibility to just pass an id to drupal but stay with the states system? Of course I'd be able to use plain javascript here, but I really like to stay strictly on the module side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find this field in `$form` array and set states currently to it.
I'm not sure, but maybe it is in `$form['field_plakat'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0][$fid]`?
It must be somewhere in this renderable `$form` array.